# Load multiple jsp page inside another jsp page div tag

Tags: jsp

In my project has three jsp page. I need to include two.jsp and three.jsp page inside one.jsp page.

one.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<c:set var ="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>

<%@include file="includes/header_admin.jsp"%>
<%@include file="includes/side_navibar.jsp" %>


<div class="page animsition">

<div id="main_page">

    <%@include file="appoinment.jsp"%>

    <%@include file="userdetails.jsp" %>


   </div>

</div>

<%@include file="includes/footer_admin.jsp" %>

</body>

</html>
```

When I include both page, only render first load page data. But only view html of second line page not render any data.If I change order show same behavior. 
Then how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post appointment.jsp and userdetails.jsp ?

Comment: Where is body open tag?

Comment: body tag isn't actually necessary in html5, in fact [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html) recommends omitting it for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because `<%@include file="filepath"%>` only include static files at the time of translation of JSP page to Servlet. So you should try for JSP action tag which will include dynamic pages at the run time.